# matching a double-quote via quote vs pattern

Tags: ruby, string-matching

Why does `check_char1` fail to find the double-quote?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

line = 'hello, "bob"'

def check_char1(line, _char)
    puts "check_char1 found #{_char} in #{line}" if line =~ /_char/
end

check_char1(line, '"')

def check_char2(line, _char)
    puts "check_char2 found #{_char.inspect} in #{line}" if line =~ _char
end

check_char2(line, /"/)
```

...and can it be made to work using `line =~ /_char/`? (How should the double-quote be passed to the method?)

Comment: _char is not a character for interpolation I believe since it is single quoted ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `_char` is just a string (i.e. no regex pattern matching needed) then just use [`String#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-include-3F)

```
if line.include?(_char)
```

If you must use a regex for this then [`Regexp.escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) is your friend:

```
if line =~ /#{Regexp.escape(_char)}/
if line =~ Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(_char))
```

and if you want `_char` to be treated like a regex (i.e. `'.'` matches anything) then drop the `Regexp.escape`:

```
if line =~ /#{_char}/
if line =~ Regexp.new(_char)
```

Answer (score 2):

In `check_char1`, `_char` in `/_char/` is treated as a literal, not a variable. You need  `/#{_char}/`.

If `_char` were treated as variable how could one enter a literal in a regex that was the name of a variable, method or constant?

Comment: What happens what `_char` is `'.'`, `'*'`, ...?

Comment: @muistooshort, I wasn't sure I understood your point until I read your answer. True, `Regexp::escape` is handy, but not essential; one could always do their own escaping.

Comment: True but `Regexp.escape` makes your intention clear and avoids missing anything in some `.*?|...` line noise (or `\p{...}`).